# Return filename without extension from full path in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm looking for a way to return fileName from full path but without extension.

```
    private static string ReturnFileNameWithoutExtension(string varFullPathToFile) {
        string fileName = new FileInfo(varFullPathToFile).Name;
        string extension = new FileInfo(varFullPathToFile).Extension;
        return fileName.Replace(extension, "");   
    }
```

Is there more bullet proof solution then replacing extension with empty string?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (fullpath);
```

Comment: what if you haven't got the full path?

Comment: It's just the same: "somefile.txt" will return "somefile"

Answer (score 6):

i'm using `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);`

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

**One More solution**

```
string fileName = new FileInfo(varFullPathToFile).Name;
fileName=fileName.Substring(0, fileName.LastIndexOf("."));
```